# how to change file_upload format in Slack webClient

Tags: python, slack-api

I'm trying to upload a CSV file in slack as message, the following Code works to upload the file:

```
import slack 
client = slack.WebClient(token='SLACK_TOKEN')

response = client.files_upload(
           channels='#Random',
           filetype='csv',
           title='Sample Report',
           file='sample.csv')
assert response["ok"]
```

however, the file gets uploaded as Textedit format not as a CSV.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

how can I upload the file as `CSV`, I thought the argument `'filetype'` will define the file as `CSV`.

Thanks in advance.

****Update****

I was able to do what I was looking for by adding the argument 'filename'.

```
import slack 
client = slack.WebClient(token='SLACK_TOKEN')

response = client.files_upload(
           channels='#Random',
           filetype='csv',
           filename='sampleReport.csv',
           title='Sample Report',
           file='sample.csv')
assert response["ok"]
```

Comment: Try with a small case 'csv'

Comment: @Sriram I did change the value to 'csv', and still the same

Comment: When I try out your example (with the corrected `csv` type) I get a CSV file on Slack, which is editable. Is this not what you want?

Comment: @ErikKalkoken I found what I was looking for by adding the argument 'filename' - Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a research here https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload

I did understand why the file was uploaded as .txt

There are 2 arguments filetype and filename. filetype provides an identifier while filename provides the file extension.

the correct code will be:

```
import slack 
client = slack.WebClient(token='SLACK_TOKEN')

response = client.files_upload(
          channels='#Random',
          filetype='csv',
          filename='sampleReport.csv',
          title='Sample Report',
          file='sample.csv')
assert response["ok"]
```